# Método replace() luego de ser aplicado al value de un input text de HTML posiciona el cursor al final

Tags: javascript, html5, input

Tengo un input text y cuando aplico el método replace() en el value del mismo, luego de hacer el reemplazo, el curso del input se posiciona al final.

Como podría hacer para que el curso no se posicione al final y se quede en la posición que está.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

const remplazar = (input) => {
    let inputValue = input.target.value;
    if (inputValue.includes('hola')) {
        input.target.value = inputValue.replace('hola', 'adios');
    }
}

input.addEventListener('input', remplazar);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="texto..">
<script src="scripts/pr.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es volver a posicionar el cursor despues del replace. Algo así como

```
const input = document.getElementById('input');

const remplazar = (input) => {
    let inputValue = input.target.value;
    if (inputValue.includes('hola')) {
        position = input.target.selectionStart;
        input.target.value = inputValue.replace('hola', 'adios');
        input.target.selectionEnd = position;
    }
}

input.addEventListener('input', remplazar);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me ayudo mucho.

Comment: @JesusAdrianMamaniTolaba, si te sirvió la respuesta, por favor márcala como aceptada para que otros usuarios sepan que esta puede ser la solución a problemas similares.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que `input.target.value` es de tipo `string` y en javascript los string son inmutables, eso significa que debes asignar un nuevo valor en vez de cambiar el que ya está. Fuente: [Does javascript have a method to replace part of a string without creating a new string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192169/does-javascript-have-a-method-to-replace-part-of-a-string-without-creating-a-new)

Si no fuera así podrías en efecto remplazar el texto sin que el cursor se moviera, pero lo que en realidad sucede es que se está borrando el texto y escribiendo uno nuevo. Así que el cursor "no sabe" donde debería estar en ese nuevo `string`.

El código solución como tal, es la respuesta que da Stefan, se puede conseguir el mismo efecto poniendo "manualmente" el cursor en la posición que decidas, en este caso conservar la posición al final del remplazo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me ayudo mucho a aclarar lo que pasaba detrás de escena.